# What is the definition of spin for photon?

Tags: photons, quantum-spin

Massless particles, as the representations of the Poincare group, are characterized  by helicity $h$ but people always say that photon has spin 1.

What is the definition of spin for photon?

Comment: [WP definition via Pauli-Lubanski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli–Lubanski_pseudovector#Helicity_representations).

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/412517/66086).

Answer (score 2):

Photon spin is the internal angular momentum of photons as described by the electromagnetic field, much like electron spin is the internal AM of the Dirac spinor field. The EM  field is a four component Lorentz vector potential, $A^\mu$, that can rotate. This rotation is EM spin. In a situation where the physics is independent of the orientation of the four vector, EM spin is conserved. The expression for EM spin is simply the Noether current associated with this symmetry.

But ... the generally accepted gauge invariant EM Lagrangian is *not* symmetric under EM potential rotation. So in the present EM theory EM spin is *not* conserved and no gauge invariant expression for photon spin exists. To remedy this a different Lagrangian can be used, the Fermi Lagrangian, which has the required symmetry. In a peer reviewed paper I propose and explore this approach. I show that it leads to a fully valid physically acceptable theory. I invite you and anybody interested in this fundamentally important issue to take a look at my work at https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0106078.

Comment: If spin is not conserved why people says that photon has spin 1?

Comment: It is conserved, just the theory does not conserve it. It is an experimental fact that a photon has spin 1.

Comment: what is the experiment that proof it?

Comment: Famous experiment by Beth, 1935. Referency is in my paper or on Wikipedia. And a great multitude of atomic physics experiments.

Comment: A modern version of Beth's experiment is described here https://phys.org/news/2016-09-photons-scientists.html .

Comment: The freely accessible paper is here : https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/2/9/e1600485