# Is it possible to increase the orbital angular momentum (OAM) of a photon?

Tags: optics, photons, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, quantum-electrodynamics

When the photon is emitted, can you change the angular speed? This has been experimented with vortex beams but I don’t quite understand how it works.
Also, an optional follow up question, would a photon’s angular speed have to be greater then it’s original speed in order to be linearly polarized or move in a curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a photon OAM switch.

The OAM of light is the component of angular momentum of a light beam that is dependent on the field spatial distribution and not the polarization.

> It can be further split into an internal and an external OAM. The internal OAM is an origin-independent angular momentum of a light beam that can be associated with a helical or twisted wavefront. The external OAM is the origin-dependent angular momentum that can be obtained as cross product of the light beam position (center of the beam) and its total linear momentum.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_angular_momentum_of_light

The photon OAM is a discrete degree of freedom that characterizes the topological charge (winding of the azimuthal phase) of a photon field with cylindrical symmetry.

> Therefore a natural question is whether a
>   topological process can be designed to create a robust
>   photonic OAM switching device with high performance.
>   Recently, the study of topological photonics has become
>   one frontier direction in optical physics with the major focus on modulating photon propagation through topological edge states [29–35], while practical topological photonic devices for on-demand switching of photon internal
>   degrees of freedom are still largely lacking.
>   Conventional spatial light modulator [23] and digital
>   micro-mirror device [24] are limited by the switching
>   rates of ∼kHz. Higher switching rates can be achieved
>   by combing acousto-optic (electro-optic) modulator with
>   SLMs (q-plate) [25, 28], or using on-chip resonators [26].
>   However, the acousto-optic modulator would induce unwanted change in wavelength, and the on-chip switching
>   has a very low efficiency. Moreover, all these approaches
>   require precise control of experimental parameters and
>   the number of usable OAM modes is usually very limited.
>   In contrast, our scheme is robust against perturbations
>   due to its topological feature, and also able to rapidly
>   switch to high OAM modes with high efficiency. Our
>   results of single-photon pumping can be generalized to
>   multi-photon states or even classic coherent states. Since
>   the system is linear with no interaction, every photon is
>   pumped independently.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.08230

[What is the orbital angular momentum (OAM) of individual photons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/99016/what-is-the-orbital-angular-momentum-oam-of-individual-photons)

Comment: Thank you. For a follow up question, is it possible for OAM to bend light instead of circular polarization or linear? This would mean that it would curve but not completely twist